# How to use AngularJS's module config with Scala.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scala, ionic-framework, scala.js

In plain JavaScript you can do:

```
angular.module('mymodule', ['ionic'])
  .config(function($someParam1, $someParam2) {
    // do something with the parameters
}
```

I am trying to do this with Scala.js. I tried the following three attempts, all of which failed:

**Attempt 1:** Use [scalajs-angular](https://github.com/greencatsoft/scalajs-angular)

```
Angular.module("mymodule", Seq("ionic")).config(MyConf)
```

Problem: `MyConf` must extend `Config` and I did not find any location where I could pass in parameters.

**Attempt 2:** Use [scalajs-angulate](https://github.com/jokade/scalajs-angulate)

```
Angular.module("mymodule", Seq("ionic")).config((a: Any, b: Any) => {...})
```

This *should* work, but I get a compiler error: `not found: value js`

**Attempt 3:** Use the dynamically typed API

```
global.angular.module("mymodule", Seq("ionic")).config((a: Any, b: Any) => {...})
```

Compiles, but the content inside the {} does not get called.

The only way I can think of now is writing a javascript based "Bridge" which does something like:

```
angular.module('mymodule', ['ionic']).config(function($a, $b) {
    com.example.myapp.MymoduleConfigurator.config($a, $b);
}
```

where `com.example.myapp.MymoduleConfigurator` is written in Scala.

Is this the only way or is there a better approach?

Comment: here is an example using scalajs-angular https://github.com/olivergg/scalajs-ionic-starttabs/blob/master/app-js/src/main/scala/com/olivergg/starttabs/IonicStartTabsApp.scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking for answers to this question. It was resolved by the OP over on [GitHub](https://github.com/jokade/scalajs-angulate/issues/45) with the workaround being to add the following import:

```
import scalajs.js
```

Also, to aid in debugging your issues, you can [add flags](https://github.com/jokade/scalajs-angulate/wiki/Debugging) to your `build.sbt` file to generate a log of the generated code to stdout at compile time like so:

```
// print code for angulate's Module enhancements 
scalacOptions += "-Xmacro-settings:biz.enef.angulate.ModuleMacros.debug"

// print code generated for calls to module.controllerOf[]
scalacOptions += "-Xmacro-settings:biz.enef.angulate.ControllerMacros.debug"

// print code generated for calls to module.directiveOf[]
scalacOptions += "-Xmacro-settings:biz.enef.angulate.DirectiveMacros.debug"

// print code generated for calls to module.serviceOf[]
scalacOptions += "-Xmacro-settings:biz.enef.angulate.ServiceMacros.debug"

// print code generated for calls to module.componentOf[]
scalacOptions += "-Xmacro-settings:biz.enef.angulate.ComponentMacros.debug"

// print code generated for function DI
scalacOptions += "-Xmacro-settings:biz.enef.angulate.AnnotationMacros.debug"

// print code generated by angulate's HttpPromise extensions
scalacOptions += "-Xmacro-settings:biz.enef.angulate.HttpPromiseMacros.debug"

// enable logging of all registered services, controllers, and directives at run time
scalacOptions += "-Xmacro-settings:biz.enef.angulate.runtimeLogging"
```